# Why do I get ERROR - TeleBot: "Infinity polling exception: 'list' object has no attribute 'id' specifically when I use new_chat_members?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

I made a bot and invited it to a group.

The bot is administrator of this group, it's not private. I'm trying to make the bot send private messages to users that join the group.

The problem is that when I try to do so, I get following error:

```
ERROR - TeleBot: "Infinity polling exception: 'list' object has no attribute 'id'
```

and I cant figure out what that means, or why I get it or how to fix it.

This is my code:

```py
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('here is bot token')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"])
def handler_new_member(message):
    first_name = message.new_chat_members[0].first_name
    bot.send_message(message.new_chat_members.id, "Something something".format(first_name))

bot.infinity_polling()
```

I tried to make the bot send private messages to new members and expected it to read the `id` of new members, which as far as I understand is possible.

I'm new to `python` and telegram api. I appreciate any help.

Comment: `message.new_chat_members[0].id` I think that is what you mean? as you are getting the first name for `[0]` as well

Comment: @python_user yeah, thank you, thats the thing

Answer (score 0):

It seems that new_chat_members is an actual list. In the first line you're using list index to get the user's first name. Lists in Python do not have attribute `id`. Maybe you meant `new_chat_members[index].id`?

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."